# How to integrate Anaconda environment (Ubuntu Windows) with VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda

I installed VS Code 1.24 on Windows 10.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 bash on Windows 10. On Ubuntu Windows, I installed Anaconda for Linux, then created a new environment `my_env`.

How can I configure VS Code to recognize `my_env`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit late but if someone has the same question.

Execute <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and look for `Terminal: Select Default Shell` there you can select if you want to execute `windows shell` or `bash` or `git bash`.

A second way is: go to **File** > **Preferences** > **Settings** there put this in user settings:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\bash.exe"
```

Here the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)